# df.value.counts() doesn't show number of occurrences in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a small sample of the data I'm working on.

[image]

I'm trying to calculate how many times the same ID appears in the data using

```
df['Total Occurences'] = df['ID'].value_counts()
```

but nothing appears in the new column.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the output of `df['ID'].value_counts()`?

Comment: The new column 'Total Occurrences' that the count should be returned into is empty.

Comment: What is the output of `print(df['ID'].value_counts())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `transform` or `value_counts` + `map` should be the preferred ways of doing it.

```
df['Total Occurences'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
```

or

```
df['Total Occurences'] = df['ID'].map(df.value_counts('ID'))
```

Both ways are much faster than the other answer for large DataFrames.

**Tests**

```
n = 10_000
# DataFrame with 'n' random IDs (50 possible values)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randint(50, size=n)})
```

```
# using groupby + transform
>>> %timeit df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
1.03 ms ± 43.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# using map + value_counts
>>> %timeit df['ID'].map(df['ID'].value_counts())
1.49 ms ± 286 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# using apply (Pedro's solution)
>>> %timeit df['ID'].apply(lambda x: df['ID'].value_counts()[x])
8.96 s ± 742 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# computing value_counts only once outside apply
>>> %%timeit 
... counts = df['ID'].value_counts()
... df['ID'].apply(lambda x: counts[x])

57.6 ms ± 246 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df['Total Occurences'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: df['ID'].value_counts()[x])
```

For performance create a variable with `df['ID'].value_counts()`:

```
count = df['ID'].value_counts()
df['Total Occurences'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: count[x])
```

Comment: This is very inefficient since you are repeating the calculation of `df['ID'].value_counts()` for every row of the DataFrame unnecessarily.

Comment: Your last test is not a fair test... You only compute `value_counts` once and you are just basically timing the `apply` part. The solution compromises two steps: computing the `value_counts` and `apply` it to the DataFrame. You can't just ignore the first... Of course it will be faster that way. The other solutions compute those two steps, not only the second...